# Different arrangements of the word PHILOSOPHY

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to figure out the number of different arrangements using all the letters in PHILOSOPHY such that the letters H,I,S,Y always stick together. The way I solved this is given below ;

Selecting a H from the 10 letters = $^2C_1$

Hence total arrangements = $^2C_1$$6!$$4!$/$(2!2!)$

I am not sure whether I have done this correctly. Appreciate any assistance thanks

Comment: Does "stick together" mean specifically "HIFY" appears in the word, or is "FYHI" ok?

Comment: @blf the order does not matter those four should be together that's it

Comment: Where is the "F" in PHILOSOPHY?

Comment: @blf I am sorry it should be S not F. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Let's set aside the problem of the two Hs for the moment; assume that they are different, say H and H*.

As you've noted, there are $6!/(2!2!)$ ways to arrange the remaining letters PPLOOH, and $4!$ ways to arrange the [H*,I,S,Y] chunk. However, you've forgotten to consider the number of ways that this chunk could fit into PPLOOH. With this information, you can calculate the number of arrangements of PHILOSOPH*Y with H*,I,S,Y staying together.

To fix the problem of the two Hs, consider what you've counted thus far. You've counted some things twice, such as PPLOOH[ISYH*] and PPLOO[H*ISY]H, when they are actually the same. You'll need to subtract these out.

Comment: Ok lets consider a five letter for consisting of HHSIFY that start and end with a H. So there are 6 ways of doing so (3*2*1). Will deducting this from $^2C_1$6!4!/(2!2!) give me the answer ?

Comment: @user81883 Read my second paragraph again: you've still forgotten how HISY fits into PPLOOH, and [at least in my method] $^{2}C_1$ doesn't make an appearance.

Comment: There are 7 slots in PPLOOH where HIFY can be put into. So we also take $^7C_1$ ?

Comment: @user81883 Yes, that's ok. For the number of ways to arrange HHSIFY such that it begins and ends with H, it should be $4!$, not $3!$.

Comment: Ya sorry 4! not 3!. So (6!4!*$^7C_1$-4!)/2!2! the final answer ?

Comment: @user81883 Not quite... you did some things in the wrong order

Comment: I don't see what I did wrong a hint please

Comment: @user81883 The subtraction is done at the wrong time.

Comment: 6!4!*$^7C_1$/(2!2!)-4! ? is this right ?